# Regular expression for splitting a URL into its component parts

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm looking for a way to split a URL into its component parts so I can handle each element. Why? Because the URL is a custom scheme in an iPhone app that I want to handle specifically.

For example, if a user taps a link with the URL myapp://section/?id=123 I want to use the string after the scheme as the indication of which section to jump to in my app and then split the key/value as an indication of which subview to present to the user.

I'm guessing a Regular Expression would do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example for the NSURL class and its usage.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"foo://name.com:8080/12345;param?foo=1&baa=2#fragment"];

NSLog(@"scheme: %@", [url scheme]); 
NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]); 
NSLog(@"port: %@", [url port]);     
NSLog(@"path: %@", [url path]);     
NSLog(@"path components: %@", [url pathComponents]);        
NSLog(@"parameterString: %@", [url parameterString]);   
NSLog(@"query: %@", [url query]);       
NSLog(@"fragment: %@", [url fragment]);
```

output:

```
scheme: foo
host: name.com
port: 8080
path: /12345
path components: (
    "/",
    12345
)
parameterString: param
query: foo=1&baa=2
fragment: fragment
```

Comment: Jeez you guys are fast! I just figured it out. I didn't realise NSUrl was so useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the docs for NSURL;

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html

scroll down to

```
Accessing the Parts of the URL
```

and see all that NSURL can do for you without a regex...

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is *serious overkill* for this. Just split first at `://`, then at `/`.

(You could have a loook at using an [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or as Bill Dudney points out, just use NSURL ;)